# The first time SCNView renders a scene is very slow

Tags: ios, scenekit, collada

I want to load Collada files dynamically in SceneKit at runtime. I have used copySceneKitAssetst to generate the .DAE file and put it my server. The app can download it from the server and use this file to init a SCNScene (refer to http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/).

There is no error when executing "./copySceneKitAssets" and the models can be rendered properly. I have called `[scnView prepareObject:gameScene shouldAbortBlock:NULL]` before setting gameScene to the scnView.scene.

The problem is that the first time scnView renders the gameScene, its very slow (a few seconds). Even the main thread is blocked during this period which means UIs cannot refresh,h and sometimes the app is killed by iOS.From the second time it renders the scene,it's very fast and main thread works well.But if we delete the App and reinstall it,the problem comes again.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which part is slow? Downloading from your server (you should be doing this in a background thread)? Processing after download? Instantiating the scene? From your description of what you've tried, it sounds like you're transferring compressed SCN files instead of DAE files (that would be good!). Why do you need to have them online instead of embedding them in your app as resources?

Comment: The scene has been instantiated.The slow part is the first time the scene show up after instantiating the scene.No matter it's SCN or DAE,it's the same.We do this because the resources must be updated at different time .

Comment: Do you find solutions? I've the same issue size of light material etc doesn't matter. 
First time I load scene I load node from .scn and add it ot scene in scene view it seems that this code happens immediately. Bot model is not showing then after few seconds it shows . Long time is between addNode -> show node in scene

Answer (score 2):

I think `prepareObjects(_:withCompletionHandler)` (defined on SCNSceneRenderer) is worth a look. It loads resources on a background thread.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I have called this function.Still slow.

Comment: Yes, I call it on  a background thread.This problem just appears when the first time to render a new dae file.No matter we reenter the scene or reopen the App,it disappears.But if we delete the App and reinstall it,the problem appears again.I guess is there any thing like create some file at sandbox  that SceneKit need to do when it render a  model the first time?